# Error al incluir un context dentro de un metodo statico

Tags: android

Estoy creando un `newInstance` dentro de un fragmento. La documentación dice que es así

```
public static Clase newInstance(int index,CheckBox check) {
    Clase categories = new Clase ();

    java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(
    this,
    now.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
    now.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE),
    check.isChecked()

    );
```

El problema es que al llamar al contexto `this.getContext()` o `Clase.this` me dice que el contexto no puede ser referenciado dentro de un método estático.

¿Alguien me podra ayudar con esto? Ya que para poder instanciar dentro de un fragmento debo hacerlo con un método estático, y en esa clase `TimePickerDialog` necesito pasar el contexto.

Answer (score 1):

La documentación dice que para un Fragment tienes que crear algo similar a:

```
public static Fragment newInstance() 
{
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    return myFragment;
}
```

pero regularmente el Contexto que se usa es el de la `Activity` estando dentro de un fragmento:

```
getActivity()
```

Puedes usar otros métodos pero considero que es lo correcto para obtener el contexto mediante `getActivity()` estando dentro del `Fragment` ya que ademas `Activity` extiende de `Context`.